# Custom Connector is giving 401 error with new connection

Tags: error, 401, custom-connector, power-platform

I have a custom connector in Power Platform. It is working fine with the older connection which was created last week.

All of sudden since yesterday, If I create a new connection and try to access the connector, I am getting below error with error

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

There are no changes made in the API which is being consumed or the Azure App that is being used for authentication.

What can be the cause of such strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You may have encountered an error recently with a Flow in Power Automate that uses custom connectors that require some sort of authentication, in which the flow stops working all of a sudden, giving you a 401 unauthorized error.

Sadly, this is a bug on Microsoft's site.